# Using string functions in ksh script

Tags: string, function, shell, ksh

I have a requirement when i would like to look for specific keyword in the arguments passed to shell script. If that keyword is present i dont want to display the value.

I tried below but its not working,also tried using awk but it looks for file input.Could you please help :

```
#!/bin/ksh

i=0
for i in $@
do
    echo $i
    if index(toupper($i),"PASSWORD") -gt 0
    then
        print "****"
    fi
done
```

Thanks

Comment: I do wonder why you would try to mask strings that are specified in clear text on the command line. You should consider them already public knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

This function might do what you ask.

The simple way of converting a string to upper case is to
use `typeset -u`.  In this case, I create a copy `$u`, so we still
have the original mixed or lower case value in `$w`

```
function shield_keyword {
    typeset -u upper;
    typeset w;
    for w in "$@";
    do
        upper=$w;
        [[ $upper == *PASSWORD* ]] && echo "****" || echo "$w" "$upper";
    done
}
```

Testing:

```
$ shield_keyword fee fie PASS WORD PASSWORD:secret special
fee FEE
fie FIE
PASS PASS
WORD WORD
****
special SPECIAL
```